# Javascript get h2 tag inside li tag and return it

Tags: javascript, function, select, element, getelementsbytagname

I want to obtain a h2 tag inside an li tag with javascript, not jquery. Currently this is the html:

```
<li vriend="Alvin Heijmans" select="">
     <img class="portret" src="img/alvin.png" />
     <div class="addbutton"></div>
     <h2>Alvin Heijmans</h2>
     <p>Utrecht</p>
</li>
```

Now I want to select the h2 tag inside the li using the following javascript:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var names = elms.getElementsByTagName('h2');
```

The console is giving the following error:

```
TypeError: elms.getElementsByTagName is not a function
var names = elms.getElementsByTagName('h2');
```

So how can this be solved?

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNodeList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.querySelectorAll()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll
http://caniuse.com/queryselector

like so:

```
var names = document.querySelectorAll('li h2');
```

which would return a NodeList (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) containing all elements matching the CSS selector: `li h2`.

Or, if you're just looking for a single element, you could just use [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) which would return a reference to the first element matching your selector.

Answer (score 2):

I believe getElementsByTagName will return an array. so for the second call you'll need to write:

```
var names = elms[0].getElementsByTagName('h2');
```

To access the first found li

Comment: We already used itration in a for loop. But then we still get the error TypeError: elms.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Comment: Then inside your iteration, replace [0] with your incremental variable. for(var i=0;i<10;i++){ elems[i].getElementsBy..... }

Comment: @Daedalus Of course "Its still an array", did I not say getElementsByTagName returns an array?

Answer (score 1):

### Edit2:

You need to use this *(looped through a `for()` to capture all of the `li` and `h2` on the page)*:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    names = [];
for (var i = 0, j = elms.length; i<j; i++) {
    names = elms[i].getElementsByTagName('h2');
}
alert(names[0].innerHTML);
```

### [JSFiddle (has alert instead of log)](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Lxe/)

**Explained:**

Your first line assigns a `node list` (represented inside of an array) with all of the `<li>` elements inside, represented by a number (starting at 0 for the first one, of course).

The second line does the same, so accessing it requires that you specify the individual node to use

Therefore, you append `[0]` to access first (in this case, only) `h2` inside of the `[0]` (first/only) `li` on the page.